# Stop ASP.NET Core 3.1 [FromForm] Converting non-zero decimal to 0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

When I `POST` to the following, it is converting the non-zero `JobNumber` to 0 instead of the sent value.

```
 [HttpPost("{testName}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<FirstPieceStamps>> PostFirstPieceStamps(string testName, [FromForm] FirstPieceStamps firstPieceStamps)
```

Here is the `FirstPieceStamps` **model**

```
public class FirstPieceStamps
    {
        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(10,3)")]
        public decimal JobNumber { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int StampID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int TestID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int UserTypeID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool Stamped { get; set; } = false;
#nullable enable
        public string? FirstName { get; set; }

        public string? LastName { get; set; }
#nullable disable
        public FirstPieceJobs FirstPieceJobs { get; set; }

        public FirstPieceTests FirstPieceTests { get; set; }

        public FirstPieceUserTypes FirstPieceUserType { get; set; }

    }
```

The `request` I'm trying to make from `Postman` to test it.

`https://localhost:5001/api/FirstPieceStamps/Layflat?JobNumber=266019.001&Stamped=true&FirstName=John&LastName=Doe`

The `JobNumber` value should be converted to a **decimal** number, *but* is instead being converted to just 0.

Comment: Is this MVC or WebAPI?

Comment: in Core they are merged.

Comment: Specify a comma (,) as a decimal separator instead of a dot (.) to check whether this is related to regional settings formatting.

Comment: How do you specify to use a comma in the model?

Comment: you need to URL Encode your url before post

Comment: It is encoded by Postman.

Comment: Are all of the other fields coming through as expected?  Is the JobNumber field the only problem?  Or could this potentially be a general model binding issue...

Comment: So for this all values except for JobNumber are coming through. But, I went to work on another part of the application with a different model and several parameters from that are not coming through, so I'm guessing it as something to do with the model binding.

Comment: Check your use of FromForm.  If you are really sending this POST as you have above, then the params are on the query string and you should be using [FromQuery] instead.  I created a fresh Core 3.1 API project with your model and this controller method and it only worked correctly when I changed FromForm to FromQuery.  If you want FromForm to work, then you need to remove them from the query string and use "form-data" option in Postman.  With FromQuery, the full JobNumber with decimals came through.

Comment: That worked! Thanks Bryan.

Comment: If you don't mind, I am going to copy my comment to an answer.  I would appreciate it if you would mark it as the answer.

Comment: [FromForm] means From Form..... Query string is NOT = Form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your use of FromForm. If you are really sending this POST as you have above, then the params are on the query string and you should be using [FromQuery] instead. I created a fresh Core 3.1 API project with your model and this controller method and it only worked correctly when I changed FromForm to FromQuery. If you want FromForm to work, then you need to remove them from the query string and use "form-data" option in Postman. With FromQuery, the full JobNumber with decimals came through.